# How can I disable gestures on a particular workspace?

Tags: macos, mission-control, multi-touch

Is it possible to disable trackpad gestures I don't want to trigger on a particular workspace?

I have virtualbox fullscreen on one of my workspaces and I'd like for mouse gestures to not trigger when I am on that workspace.

Answer (score 4):

#### This is not a feature provided by OS X.

You have to disable unwanted gestures in **System Preferences → Trackpad** and then use a third-party tool to enable customized gestures.

E.g. You can use **[BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/)** to define gestures on a *per-app* basis. This will allow to simply not set set any gestures for virtualbox.

[image]